# Jquery specific div selection without using accordian

Tags: php, jquery

HI,

I'm trying to get accordion like functionality without using jQuery's UI accordion feature.

How can I select the related (child?) div to open when using a link attached to a `dt` element?

**At present my code is**

```
<div id="listings">
  <dl class="listings">
    <dt>
      Get the Milk
    </dt>
    <dd>
      Due Date: 17th Oct
    </dd>
    <dd>
      <a href="#" class="more">more details 2</a>
    </dd>
    <dd>
      <a href="#">mark as complete</a>
    </dd>
  </dl>
  <div class="more_details">
    <p>
      This is some details about the task that I would to have appear when
      the more details 1 link is clicked
    </p>
  </div>
  <dl class="listings">
    <dt>
      Go to Work
    </dt>
    <dd>
      Due Date: 22th Oct
    </dd>
    <dd>
      Site: None
    </dd>
    <dd>
      <a href="#" class="more">more details 2</a>
    </dd>
    <dd>
      <a href="#">mark as complete</a>
    </dd>
  </dl>
  <div class="more_details">
    <p>
      This is some details about the task that I would to have appear when
      the more details 2 link is clicked
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**The jQuery I'm using is**

```
$('.more').click(function() {
    $('.more_details').slideToggle('fast', function() { });
    return false;
});
```

But the problems I have are

1. When the link with class more is clicked, naturally all the more_details divs open
2. The amount of items in the list will vary as they are being generated from a database query so I cant used fixed, unique class names

Thanks

Jz

Comment: This is now Solved - many Thanks. I would vote you up, but I need 15 rep points first:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basics are you need to go from `this` and find the element relatively using [tree traversal](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) (moving around the DOM from where you clicked).  The easiest way looks like this:

```
$('#listings .more').click(function(e) {
  $(this).closest('.listings').next('.more_details').slideToggle('fast');
  e.preventDefault();
});​
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/6YmSL/).  This goes from the `.more` you clicked on up to the `.listings` element using [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) then get's its [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) sibling (`.more_details`) and does a [`.slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) on that (no need for the callback if you're not doing anything in it).

---

However, a more efficient way to do this once you have more than a few items in your list is to use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) so there's just one `click` handler up on `#listings`, like this:

```
$('#listings').delegate('.more', 'click', function(e) {
  $(this).closest('.listings').next('.more_details').slideToggle('fast');
  e.preventDefault();
});​
```

[You can test that version out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/6YmSL/1/).

Comment: Thanks Nick. Great resource in JSfiddle btw.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery's [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) and [parent](http://api.jquery.com/parents/):

```
 $(this).parents('.listings').next('.more_details').slideToggle('fast', function() { });
```

This will go 'up' the dom and find a .listings element (note that if you have more .listings elements even higher up, add .first() after it. Then next('.more_details') examines 'sibblings' to find one that suites the definition of '.more_details'.

There's another option if you are willing to change your html. Surround both the dl and the div with another tag, give it a class name, say '.listing_container'. Then you can do $(this).parents('.listing_container').find('.more_details'). This would work better if you have cases where a listing is not followed by it's own .more_details element.